# Why my `onclick` doesn't work despite others things works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using some parts of [gentelella](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) and there is a file `custom.js`. I have some problems with this file because some parts works and other don't.

The problem is with this method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("custom.js inside document ready");


    $('.collapse-link').on('click', function() {
        console.log("clicked on a collapse-link");

        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel'),
            $ICON = $(this).find('i'),
            $BOX_CONTENT = $BOX_PANEL.find('.x_content');

        // fix for some div with hardcoded fix class
        if ($BOX_PANEL.attr('style')) {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200, function(){
                $BOX_PANEL.removeAttr('style');
            });
        } else {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200);
            $BOX_PANEL.css('height', 'auto');
        }

        $ICON.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });

    $('.close-link').click(function () {
        console.log("close-link clicked")
        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel');

        $BOX_PANEL.remove();
    });
});
```

It write "custom.js inside document ready" but when I click nothing happened.

And if I look into the HTML I have the same classes as in the JS:
[image]

Comment: can you put together an example and upload it on jsfiddle ?

Comment: The answer is the one of @goldylucks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be that on document ready these specific elements are not found.
In general a best practice is to delegate the events to the document, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("custom.js inside document ready");


    $(document).on('click', '.collapse-link' /* <--- notice this */, function() {
        console.log("clicked on a collapse-link");

        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel'),
            $ICON = $(this).find('i'),
            $BOX_CONTENT = $BOX_PANEL.find('.x_content');

        // fix for some div with hardcoded fix class
        if ($BOX_PANEL.attr('style')) {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200, function(){
                $BOX_PANEL.removeAttr('style');
            });
        } else {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200);
            $BOX_PANEL.css('height', 'auto');
        }

        $ICON.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.close-link' /* <--- notice this */, function () {
        console.log("close-link clicked")
        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel');

        $BOX_PANEL.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: OMG you are a real hero ! What is the difference between your method and mine ? I understand that with your it search the `collapse-link` and with mine it listen right ?

Comment: You are listening directly to the elements `.collapse-link` and `.close-link`, and they are probably not present on `document.ready`, so actually you are not listening to anything. You can verify this by running `$ ('.close-link')` on `document.ready` and c if u get anything back.  


I am listening to the `document` itself, and I say "if the click comes from `.close-link` then to X".  

Makes sense?

Comment: Not sure I agree with "In general a best practice is to delegate [..] to document". Why would this be preferable to delegating to a parent div, for example?

Comment: @goldylucks oh okay I understand and yes it makes sense ! Yes I'll mark it but I need to wait

Comment: @Jerome Because your buttons are dynamically created. The code you had get executed before they're created so when it gets executed, none of your future button get attached to the event listeners. But in event delegation you're not attaching the events to the elements you want, but instead you're attaching them to a static element (in this example, the `document`) which an is element that have been there since the document loaded.

Comment: @Jerome And you're basically saying, "hay Mr. static element, look when a click happen would you check if that element match this selector (`<<noice this`) for me, if so then execute this function!".

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir your example helped me a lot to understand, I have learn something new today :) Thank you

Comment: @Mackan it's more future proof. the document will always be there. that parent div might move in the future. of course the real best practice would be to let jQuery die and move to a data binding framework like react :)

Answer (score 0):

You have written the click event on the a tag. In general functional specific tags like submit button, a tag will do their default functionality on click. So as it is anchor it will check for href which is not there so the it is not redirecting to anywhere. We can supress the default behaviour of these kinds using e.preventDefault(). Here e is  the event. So change your function to

```
$('.collapse-link').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked on a collapse-link");

        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel'),
            $ICON = $(this).find('i'),
            $BOX_CONTENT = $BOX_PANEL.find('.x_content');

        // fix for some div with hardcoded fix class
        if ($BOX_PANEL.attr('style')) {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200, function(){
                $BOX_PANEL.removeAttr('style');
            });
        } else {
            $BOX_CONTENT.slideToggle(200);
            $BOX_PANEL.css('height', 'auto');
        }

        $ICON.toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });
```

And

```
$('.close-link').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("close-link clicked")
        var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel');

        $BOX_PANEL.remove();
});
```